# How to change default highlighted color of dropdown in handsontable to another color

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, background-color, handsontable

I have a `Handsontable` as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/nt001ymn/22/

I have drop downs in my table as well. When I look through the **drop-down its highlighted using light Gray colour by default**. Please check the image below:

[image]

How can I change the highlighted colour to another colour . Say I want to change the highlighted colour to yellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default grey background is from the imported handsontable CSS file.
To override it, please add the following CSS style in your own CSS file:

```
.handsontable.listbox tr td.current, .handsontable.listbox tr:hover td {
    background: yellow !important;
}
```

Hope this help you! ;)

Comment: Thanks buddy it helped.

Answer (score 3):

Just add this CSS:

```
.handsontable.listbox tr:hover td {
  background: #FF0; 
}
```

I can also explain how I got there, so you learn 'how to fish':

- On Chrome, open the page and hit F12 to open developer tools
- Open the dropdown, mouse hover on an option and hit CTRL+SHIFT+C or Cmd + Shift + C on Mac to start 'inspect mode'.
- Select the option you are hovering and you see the CSS / HTML for it.
- Looking at the Styles panel on dev tools it's easy to understand that CSS line is the one controlling the highlight color.
- On the styles panel change that color to yellow and see the result. Happy with it? done. just put that on your .css file :)

[Video on how to do it](http://cl.ly/1u411k40421S). After I do it using these steps I also show you how to manually change the state of something to be simulating that it's 'hovered' so that it's easy to understand what CSS is going on there.

Answer (score 2):

[Working Edited code here](http://jsfiddle.net/nt001ymn/27/)

The css updated, please check

```
.handsontable.listbox tr td.current, .handsontable.listbox tr:hover td {
background: #ff0;
```

}

Comment: AAh so many answers already there by the time I was posting .. Ok but keeping this answer as well .:)

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite this class:

```
.handsontable.listbox tr td.current, 
.handsontable.listbox tr:hover td {
      background: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.handsontable.listbox tr td.current {
background-color : green;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

add your css

```
.handsontable.listbox tr td.current, .handsontable.listbox tr:hover td{
   background-color: yellow
}
```